# не выполняется cron

Tags: cron

Ubuntu 20.04 cron не выполняет действие по обновлению остатков товара.

Запускается и работает в таком виде через планировщик стороннего хостинга:

`wget -O /dev/null 'https://my.site/index.php?route=extension/module/ms_integration/updateStock'`

Пробовал варианты:
`*/10 * * * * wget -O - 'https://my.site/index.php?route=extension/module/ms_integration/updateStock' > /dev/null 2>&1`

`*/10 * * * * wget -qO /dev/nul https://my.site/index.php?route=extension/module/ms_integration/updateStock`

`*/10 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null 'https://my.site/index.php?route=extension/module/ms_integration/updateStock' /dev/null 2>&1`

`*/10 * * * * wget -q --spider 'https://my.site/index.php?route=extension/module/ms_integration/updateStock'`

`*/10 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null "https://my.site/index.php?route=extension/module/ms_integration/updateStock"`

Другие задачи выполняются:
`*/10 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null "https://my.site/index.php?route=cireviewpro/cireviewcron/schedule&yJgWbXlzZWNyZXRjb2Rlm3kt3V=yJgWm3kt3V"`

`*/10 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null "https://my.site/index.php?route=cireviewpro/cireviewcron/cron&yJgWbXlzZWNyZXRjb2Rlm3kt3V=yJgWm3kt3V"`

Где может быть ошибка? С другого хостинга всё работает по расписанию

Comment: крон может быть не запущен. спросите в поддержке хостинга

Comment: Крон запущен и выполняет задания. У меня сервер) Не выполняется конкретно эта задача, остальные работают. Если ее запустить со стороннего хостинга - работает.

Comment: вгет укажи с полным путём